# Do not make the application open a new window more updating an html tag

Tags: javascript, java, applet, java-web-start

I have a JApplet application. It has a button that clicking it takes the data entered in the textfield and plays in a url that is a index.jsp. In index.jsp page has the following code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JNLP</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Funcao que faz a aplicacao abrir automaticamente.
        function OpenInNewTab(url) {
            var win = window.open(url,'_blank');
            win.focus();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload = OpenInNewTab("jnlp.jsp")>
       <p><%=request.getParameter("name") %><p>
</body>
</html>
```

The Applet class has this method to the button click:

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){ 

        // String to get the user input texts 
        //String str1 = (this.key_text1.getText());

      String nome = this.textfield.getText();
      System.out.println(nome);
      //aqui eu envio para a servlet.
      String path = "index.jsp";
      try{
          if(){
              URL url = new URL(getDocumentBase(),path+"?nome="+nome);
              getAppletContext().showDocument(url);
              System.out.println(url);
          }
      }catch(MalformedURLException e){
          showStatus("Não encontrado.");
      }
```

The problem is that when the guy enters the JTextField field is showing another index.jsp page instead of the page to receive the value. I did not want to click on the application java web start open a new window. It would not have worked something like ajax to show the value that was entered in the textfield field?

Comment: `var win = window.open(url,'_blank');` Why is `_blank` in there? That ***specifies*** a new, blank tab/window.

Comment: I want the application to the person clicking that link the application to open automatically. Was there a better way to do this?

Comment: I need just a piece of jsp page is updated, only the way it is is updating again.

I wanted the URL with the parameter that the user typed appear as ajax. That is, is this: http: // localhost: 8080 / jnlpproject when the user clicks the button, with no page refresh, but the URL would be http: // localhost:8080/jnlpproject?name=aline